# Unsupported Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, soap

I'm attempting to use the web service to retrieve data from server. I follow the tutorial specified in http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise5.html, of course I've modified the original code to satisfied my demands.

Now I'm getting an error like this: Unsupported Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]

To see the full error, I write a new error function when getting data:

```
var errorFn = function(e){

    for(var p in e){
    alert(e[p]);
    }
}

var successFn = function(resp){

    var data='';
    if(resp){
    //getting the data from the response object
        data=resp.data;         
    }

        //Some other code here... 

}

getData("/entity",null,successFn,errorFn);
```

And the browser alert the error object:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 Unsupported Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /vehicle. Reason:
<pre>    Unsupported Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.UnsupportedMediaException: Unsupported Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.decode(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at $Proxy32.getAllVehicles(Unknown Source)

    at com.google.appengine.codelab.soap.client.VehicleServlet.doGet(VehicleServlet.java:52)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)

    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)

    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)

    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)

    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)

    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)

    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)

    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:370)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)

    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)

    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)

    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

</pre>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                

</body>
</html>
```

Somebody help me with this problem ??

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Add the following code in the head of the class:

```
@BindingType("http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/2003/05/soap/bindings/HTTP/")
```

Then restart your server.

Comment: Just to add more info to this answer, this annotation makes sure SOAP 1.2 is used instead of SOAP 1.1. https://jax-ws.java.net/2.1.5/docs/soap12.html

Answer (score 3):

This error has happend to me and the reason was that the call to the webservices was made to an invalid host, so the web server responds with a http error message instead of an xml soap message.

Answer (score 1):

I my case, same error, but different reason:

The Port wasn't specified in the wsdl, which the Server gave back to the Java Service "Generator".
Therefore the Webserver answered the SOAP call, with a Homepage, which of course wasn't text/XML but text /html.

Adding the Port to the wsdl solved the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: your client (browser?) is sending data as `Content-Type: text/html` while it should be `Content-Type: application/soap+xml` (for [old SOAP](http://hadleynet.org/marc/whatsnew.html#S3.7.1) also `Content-Type: text/xml`).

So if you are making requests by hand you should add the [`Content-Type` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) to your HTTP requests.

Comment: Yes I think so @Peter but where can I config the HTTP requests, in the servlet class or somewhere in /war directory??

Comment: @Peter Where do we need to specify the Content-Type header? HTTP Request is not with me. We just call an exposed method from wsdl.

I am sure I am missing something. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur when composing SOAP request and the content provided is improperly encoded/formated/inaccessible. This is probably not the case of yours, but if someone else encounters identical error *before* sending the request, it means that the data used to compose the message itself or *it's attachments* are improperly encoded, formated or generally inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

Try other clients . 
in my case the problem occurs in jdeveloper 11.1.2.0 (Http analyser as client) and solved by Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3 (Http analyser as client)

This problem comes from request Content-Type

Answer (score 0):

I had also encountered this problem, and finally I found out that was caused by the server.

The server is built on Node.js, and was **concurrently** using two packages `multer` and `formidable` to parse 'multipart/form-data' type form data. That caused the conflict: the actual form parser `formidable` can't get the raw form data because of `multer` has already processed that and got a clean content. We removed `multer`, then the problem was solved.